# Show only if currentTime > scheduleEnd using gravity forms

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show a shortcode only if the current time is before the closetime.

I am using this conditional in my page.php but is not working:

```
$closeTime = strtotime($form['scheduleEnd'] . " " .         $form['scheduleEndHour'] . ":" . $form['scheduleEndMinute'] . " " . $form['scheduleEndAmpm']);
            $currentTime = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i a'));
            if ($currentTime > $closeTime) {
                echo do_shortcode('[stickylist id="'.get_field( 'id_form' ).'" showto="creator"]'); 
            }
```

I think is because i am not adding what form is anywhere in the main function but I am not really sure how can I get this to work.

Thank you!

Comment: add the result of a `var_dump($form)` to your question. Probably, the error is in the format of your string.